# Email marketing automation software that can pull information from my in-house CRM

Tags: email, automation

There are tons of marketing automation software out in the market such as hubspot, drip, moosend, springsharp). Instead of building one from scratch what is the fastest way to integrate with these systems with the least amount of development effort.

These companies all have API's but that means I need to build the UI from scratch. I would like to be able to use these companies front end and back end which integrates with my CRM?

Does anyone have some recommendations for implementation and also potential companies that offer this type of integration?

Comment: What is your CRM? Or are you planning to switch to a different CRM?

Comment: We built the CRM in-house with angular5 frontend and .NET backend.

Comment: What should the email marketing automation pull from your in-house CRM? Just a list of email addresses? Or lists of email addresses based on a category name, or on a kind of search string in a given query language? Should the software also *put* information into your databases, for instance number of retries or unsubscribe data?

Comment: Yes it pulls email address and some profile information e.g status. If the status changes from that individual an automated email will be sent out. We would like to use the drag and drop features to build a nice marketing email and also the automated workflows. So instead of building the UI on our CRM we would like to leverage a 3rd party such as hubspot, drop, moosend.

Answer (score 0):

[Mautic](https://www.mautic.org/) is an email marketing automation suite which is open source, meaning it can be adapted to any CRM.

It already has a [plugin to pull contacts from SugarCRM](https://www.mautic.org/docs/en/plugins/sugarcrm.html).

So, you could copy the SugarCRM plugin and adapt it your CRM. Or see how it pulls contacts and implement the same. Depending on your security needs, you might want to remove OAuth and replace it with the same authentication scheme that your in-house CRM uses.

Of course, there is some development involved. Many companies offer Mautic customization so you should have no problem finding a Mautic integration company. Like most other tools, Mautic also offers CSV import of contacts as a low tech/low cost option.

[image: SugarCRM Mautic integration fields synchronization pull push]